# Can someone tell me how to show this is linearly independent or not without using Wronskian?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Not sure how to do this without using the Wronskian.

Comment: Hint:  what do you know about $e^{a+b}$?

Comment: It's equal to $e^{a}*e^b$

Comment: Right, so $e^{x+1}=?$

Comment: @lulu $$e^{x}e$$

Comment: True.  So the second function is a constant times the first.  Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 1):

The set of four functions are dependent.

Note that $$ e\times  e^x + (-1)\times e^{x+1} +0\times e^{x^2}+0\times sin(x) =0$$ without the coefficients being all $0$

If you through away one of $e^x$  or $e^{x+1}$, then you have a set of three independent functions.